# Run commands on Raspbian boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I created a Django project which communicate another Python process (called gateway). All works fine. Both projects are using virtualenv, so, it's necessary activate virtualenv to execute the projects

To execute gateway, I open a terminal:

```
#activate virtual env:
pi@raspberrypi: source venv/bin/activate

#go to archive folder
(venv) pi@raspberry cd PFCProject/PFC

#executes
(venv) pi@raspberry python arduinoserver.py
```

After, I have to initialize django server:

```
#activate virtual env:
pi@raspberrypi: source venv/bin/activate

#go to archive folder
(venv) pi@raspberry cd PFCProject/PFC

#executes
(venv) pi@raspberry python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I have to open 2 terminals and executes the commands in each one.

The question is: how can I create commands, which execute the above tasks when Raspberry starts? It's necessary to execute gateway before Django project.

Comment: What version of Raspbian you are using? I'm looking for a solution with `systemd`. Have you made two bash scripts? Does they run on the command line? Can you put all commands in one script?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use rc.local. It's run on startup.

You need to use absolute paths, though. And I'd recommend moving your arduinoserver.py script to your virtualenv's bin directory as per [this documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/), or this won't work.

It looks like you don't actually have to "activate" virtualenv (see above link), as long as things are in the right directory.

So to do this, I'd recommend [making your python scripts executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304883/what-do-i-use-on-linux-to-make-a-python-program-executable), and then running them as the default user. (See below rc.local commands.) Note that you'd want your #!/path/to/python to point to your virtualenv's python interpreter, and not your system's default.

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# *** Your scripts/commands go here.
su -s /bin/bash -c /path/to/your/script/arduinoserver.py your_username&
su -s /bin/bash -c /path/to/your/script/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 your_username&

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

install nano if havent already done so:

```
sudo apt-get install nano
```

then create a new shell file:

```
cd /home/pi

nano onstartup.sh
```

should be a blank file.
add your scripts.
save the file.

open cron tab:

```
crontab -e
```

if prompted for text editor press <kbd>enter</kbd> for nano
add:

```
@reboot /home/pi/onstartup.sh
```

hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks! last question: actually , i have to open 2 terminals and executes the commands in each one.

In this case, i have to write 2 shell files? it's possible to add 2 files in crontab and make one shell executes after other?

Comment: yes just do @reboot then the 2 files the first to exicute needs to be put in first!

Comment: @FelipeFonsecabh if that does not work in cron tab, use ths: `@reboot /home/pi/onstartup2.sh | at now + 2 minutes` this will garintee that the first starts the after 2 minutes the second shell script will run. ***Hope it helps!*** ***Can you accept this answer?***

Comment: Hi! No one shell file works

When i use the crontab -e command, it creates a crontab file in tmp folder. After restart, the file does'nt not executed and it disappear.

I try to edit the crontab file in /etc folder, but not works to.

Any idea?

Comment: are you on raspberry pi 3? newest version?

Comment: Yes. I try this command in crontab file: (i can't put arroba caracther)
reboot bash /home/pi/startgateway.sh  && bash /home/pi/startwebserver.sh

Is there any difference between this code bellow?
reboot bash /home/pi/startgateway.sh
reboot bash /home/pi/startwebserver.sh

Comment: no there usnt, do `@reboot bash [your path]` dont forget the@ sign

Answer (score 0):

As with User98764431's answer, you can create a shell executable and run it in cron, but this doesn't seem to work, you say. Just create 2 shell files containing your separate scripts and add this `crontab` entry:
`@reboot sh firstfile.sh && sh secondfile.sh`. This runs the first shell file then the other.